# How do I find the TNS path used by a .NET Application?

Tags: c#, oracle, tnsnames, tns

I have the following error and I'd like to

ORA-12154 TNS: impossibile risolvere l'identificativo di connessione specificato

In english sounds like:

ORA-12154 TNS: it's impossible to find the specified connection identifier

But in witch file? **I've more than one oracle client installed**. I'd like to execute a .NET code witch says where is located the TNS file. 
I've seen this problem for five years in my company with no one trying to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows OS, with Oracle 10g installed on C drive, it would be like this:

```
C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_2\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
```

BUT, this is for client programs like PL/SQL Developer and TOAD.

If you are talking about .Net provider.

I install Oracle 11g Client:

```
C:\oracle\app\MyUserName\product\11.2.0\client_2\Network\Admin\tnsnames.ora
```

Change the connection identifiers in the 2nd file to control what .Net "Sees" as oracle connections either as Server Explorer connection wizard or as .Net code.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

the file you are looking for is named `tnsnames.ora`. The location depends on the OS you are using. Try to look at the TNS_ADMIN registry entry value, it should point to that file. Another tip: if the path containing `tnsnames.ora` contains `'('` or `)` as for example `( x86` ) you can experience troubles, so change the location.

Comment: That should be "tnsnames.ora" though (not "tsnames.ora") ;-)